# Confused about desktop/viewport switching, want to bind keyboard shortcuts to switch desktops

Tags: 10.04, gnome, compiz

I've installed a pre-made Ubuntu 10.04 image at work, and I can't seem to figure out how to get desktop switching to work. No shortcuts work, and all the help I can get from the Ubuntu forums is "CTRL-Alt-Left/Right should work."

So let me get this straight. Switching between desktops is deprecated, so we use viewports, which are managed by Compiz, which has one of the most absurd configuration managers out there. Lovely.

Can anyone straighten this out for me, and anyone else who might stumble on this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting them in the keyboard shortcuts? Seems to work fine over here:

[image]

(You can click on the shortcut field for each function and then the tool will prompt you to set a shortcut)

Comment: I don't see any of those fields in my Keyboard Shortcuts...

Comment: @Alex Can you update your question with a screenshot of what your keyboard shortcuts does look like?

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm using 11, so the details may differ a little.

You'll need to install Advanced Desktop Effects Settings (ccsm) if it isn't already, and run it.

Under **Desktop Wall** click on the **Bindings** tab.

Under **Move within wall** for **Move Left**, **Move Right** ,etc click the first button on the right (it will say **Disabled** or give a key combination).

Select **Enabled** and click **Grab key combination**

Press the keys you want to use for the shortcut.

[image: Desktop Wall - Bindings]

I have the same config as Jorge Castro so I don't think the Gnome and Compiz settings will conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend asking whoever pre-made that image for you, if none of the other answers work as expected. It could be that there's some obscure, custom setting that your image has that changes the default behaviour.